# What is the best practice for defining different shortcut keys for separate keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, brightness, remapping

## Context

I have Razer Blade 14 laptop, and I use a Apple Wireless Keyboard (version 2). The Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts section only allows me to define one keyboard layout for both keyboards.

## Problem

This is confusing because things like F1 through F12 have icons on them on both devices. But those icons do not match up.

For example, F1 on the built-in keyboard is "Volume Mute". But on the wireless keyboard it's "Decrease Screen Brightness".

## Question

So I'm wondering what is considered the best practice for defining two keyboard layouts?

Ideally I'd like to have a GUI to do this. But I understand that may not exist and I may be left editing user or system configuration files.

Researching this topic has left me with what appear to be multiple ways of doing this but I'm unclear as to which is proper - if any.

*Thank you for your time!*

Comment: You can have multiple layouts and manually select one or other depending on the intended use. However, the OS (any OS) is unable to guess the correct one. The answer depends on knowing which Ubuntu version/favor you're running because it varies depending on the desktop environment.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 + GNOME 3.24.2

Comment: http://linuxblog.darkduck.com/2013/10/how-to-configure-keyboard-layouts-in-unity-gnome3-kde.html

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't appear to be the solution. Although it does allow you to switch languages it doesn't preserve shortcut keys.